# Watermark detection in Python

Tags: deep-learning, keras, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I have a lot of images and I would like to be able to classify them into two groups: one containing images with watermarks and one containing images without any watermark.

There are about 40 different watermarks. I created "fake" watermarked images to train a CNN and it worked very well on the "fake" validation set but not on the real images. Plus it was a long shot because I would have needed to train a model for each watermark (and I don't have the original watermark) or train a big model.

I quit the watermark approach to try and find text. So I tried OpenCV text detection and it really wasnt working since the text is crooked and not that different from the background.

Is there an easy solution I missed? Any idea is welcolme. I am kinda new to machine learning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question! Maybe the [pretrained models](https://keras.io/applications/) in Keras can help. Either by means of transfer learning, so that you might have to label only a small number of images by hand to retrain the higher layers. Or by using them for feature extraction and see if a certain keyword appears frequently for watermarked images.

Or just upload the pictures some place that does not allow watermarks and see if they get flagged ;-)

Comment: Thank you ! I'm going to try both approches and I'll let you know if I managed to get results :)

Comment: I've manually identified 1400 images as watermarked or not and split them for training/testing. I fined tuned the last convolutional block and the top level dense layers and it achieved 80% accuracy with no hyperparameter tuning which is a good start I think

Comment: Excellent! Now you could build a [generative adversarial network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) that generates better fake watermarks ;-)

Comment: Wooow that would be insane I'm going to try this after tuning the current model ;)